# Why are my CSS changes not being saved?

Tags: theming

I have a file for my homepage in the directory `libraries/css/2017-06_Su****.css` I'm making changes to the url path of where the background image is being pulled from and the path change is not taking changes. It's still the old path.

I tried cleaning cache, turned off caching and ran `drush cc` all

This is my css:

```
.banner-background{
 background:url(https://www.no******.org/images/homepage/2017/06/Summer2017_header_1170x470.jpg);
    }
```

I'm changing this to:

```
.banner-background{
            background:url(https://www.no******.org/images/homepage/2017/06/Summer2017_header_1170x470__.jpg);
    }
```

It keeps showing up as this below no matter what I do

```
.banner-background{
 background:url(https://www.no******.org/images/homepage/2017/06/Summer2017_header_1170x470.jpg);
    }
```

I'm wondering why when I modify my css in drupal 7 why the changes aren't being saved although all caching is turned off.

Comment: Have you try adding !important tag at the end of url.? and see if that takes effect? 
background:url('https://www.no******.org/images/homepage/2017/06/Summer2017_header_1170x470__.jpg') !important;

it should work normally if you clear all caches from drush but seems like it's not the problem that you are having.. editing the correct file ?

Comment: Have you also ruled out your browser cache by force reloading the page (Ctrl + F5).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, nothing seemed to help. It turned out that the problem was that the page for which the css did not follow the changes was created by a custom plugin. That plugin has a method that returns an array that is used for rendering.

If not specified, caching is default on, and the cached css was always used. In my case specifying the cashing had immediate effect.

In function `build` (which returns the render data), I changed

```
    return array(
        '#markup' => "<div class='taxoblock'>REST HTML</div>",);
```

to

```
    return array(
        '#markup' => "<div class='taxoblock'>REST HTML</div>",
        '#cache'    => array (   'max-age'   => 0 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to "Home › Administration › Configuration › Development > Performance" and disabling "Aggregate and compress CSS files"? After doing it, refresh cache.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/) module and put it into development mode.